# Import SQLite to Python 3.7.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, import

I am currently still a target Python beginner. I want to build a small tool with a database.

Currently I fail at the very beginning with the command

```
import sqlite3
```

I always get the following error message

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module was not found.
```

I am currently using Python 3.7.6.

Do you have any idea what this could be ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: post the full traceback you get. By any chance is your file named `sqlite3.py`?

Comment: The fail ist named `ToDoList_Main.py`. 
The full traceback is this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/***/ToDoList_Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "***", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\****\miniconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

Comment: it seems the installation of your package was not successful as some *.dll files are missing